# Laravel project on docker SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = myDb )

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, docker, laravel-8

good evening I have a problem with docker to connect to my database

when I do a docker-compose up -d && docker-compose ps the server is starting but I get an error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = myDb and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

I don't quite understand why

here is the content of my docker-compose.yml

```
    #base de donnees
    database:
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports:
            - 3307:3307
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=myDb
            - MYSQL_ROOT_USER =root
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

here is the content of my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=myDb
DB_USERNAME=secret
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**Note:** I am on an ubuntu vps and I would like to know is it worth using the vps ip somewhere.

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are they networked?

Comment: Shouldn't the port mapping be 3307 : 3306?

Comment: @Jaquarh yes they are networked wait i send all content of docker-compose.yml

Comment: @nnichols ok I'll try that it's my first experience with laravel

Comment: @Jaquarh Thank you very much for your precious help and especially for your time thank you again, it's solved it's nnichois who is right, it's a port problem

Comment: @nnichols You are absolutely right, that was the problem for the resolution in docker-compose.yml I put 3307:3306 and I kept 3306 in .env.
thank you very much for everything (your time and sharing) thank you